# How do I fix this syntax error with sql_check?

Tags: sql, r

this is my second project I'm working on in R and I ran into this error message and don't know how to get through this. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

[image]

At first I kept getting %>% can't be found, so I reinstalled dplyr and it worked. Now I'm unsure how to get past this message.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064). It makes it harder for other to search for similar errors.

Comment: This looks more like a SQL problem. Are you missing `FROM` between `*` and the table name?

Comment: Yes, that was exactly it! I totally missed that, thank you!